# query xpath with php

Tags: php, xpath

I wrote following php code to extract nodes information from this xml:

```
<sioctBoardPost rdfabout="http//boards.ie/vbulletin/showpost.php?p=67075">
  <rdftype rdfresource="http//rdfs.org/sioc/ns#Post" />
  <dctitle>hib team</dctitle>
  <siochas_creator>
    <siocUser rdfabout="http//boards.ie/vbulletin/member.php?u=497#user">
      <rdfsseeAlso rdfresource="http//boards.ie/vbulletin/sioc.php?sioc_type=user&amp;sioc_id=497" />
    </siocUser>
  </siochas_creator>
  <dctermscreated>1998-04-25T213200Z</dctermscreated>
  <sioccontent>zero, those players that are trialing 300 -400 pingers? umm..mager lagg and even worse/</sioccontent>
</sioctBoardPost>

<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("boards.xml");
$products[0] = $xml->xpath("/sioctBoardPost/sioccontent");
$products[1] = $xml->xpath("/sioctBoardPost/dctermscreated");
$products[2] = $xml->xpath("/sioctBoardPost/@rdfabout");
print_r($products);
  ?>
```

This gives following output:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => zero, those players that are trialing for hib team, (hpb's) most of them are like 300 -400 pingers? umm..mager lagg and even worse when they play on uk server's i bet/ ) ) [1] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 1998-04-25T213200Z ) ) [2] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [rdfabout] => http//boards.ie/vbulletin/showpost.php?p=67075 ) ) ) 
)
```

But I need only nodes content as an output i.e without Array([0] => Array etc.

Output should be like this:

```
zero, those players that are trialing for hib team, (hpb's) most of them are like 300 -400 pingers? umm..mager lagg and even worse when they play on uk server's i bet

1998-04-25T213200Z

http//boards.ie/vbulletin/showpost.php?p=67075
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you show your xml file?

Comment: <sioctBoardPost rdfabout="http//boards.ie/vbulletin/showpost.php?p=67075">
 <rdftype rdfresource="http//rdfs.org/sioc/ns#Post" />
 <dctitle>hib team</dctitle>
 <siochas_creator>
  <siocUser rdfabout="http//boards.ie/vbulletin/member.php?u=497#user">
   <rdfsseeAlso rdfresource="http//boards.ie/vbulletin/sioc.php?sioc_type=user&amp;sioc_id=497"/>
  </siocUser>
 </siochas_creator> 
 <dctermscreated>1998-04-25T213200Z</dctermscreated>
 <sioccontent>zero, those players that are trialing 300 -400 pingers? umm..mager lagg
and even worse/</sioccontent>
 </sioctBoardPost>

Answer (score 1):

You can use `current()` to only get the first element of each XPath result (which is an array) and then use a `(string)` cast to get the node contents:

```
$products[0] = (string)current($xml->xpath("/sioctBoardPost/sioccontent"));
$products[1] = (string)current($xml->xpath("/sioctBoardPost/dctermscreated"));
$products[2] = (string)current($xml->xpath("/sioctBoardPost/@rdfabout"));
print_r($products);
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion and you code return following output: Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => hib team ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => zero, those players that are trialing for hib team, (hpb's) most of them are like 300 -400 pingers? umm..mager lagg and even worse when they play on uk server's i bet/ ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 1998-04-25T213200Z ) [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [rdfabout] => http//boards.ie/vbulletin/showpost.php?p=67075 ) ) )  but I dont want the word SimpleXMLElement Object in output.

Comment: @MuhammadShahzadFaisal You may need an additional `(string)` cast.

Comment: Actually I dont know how to apply (string) cast on this, kindly help me how to do that.

Comment: @MuhammadShahzadFaisal I've shown you in my updated answer, please check.

Comment: @MuhammadShahzadFaisal Cool, if all is well, please consider to accept this answer by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you have observed, the `xpath()` method returns an array of matched nodes, so you need to deal with the elements of the returned arrays.  I believe this should work in this case:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("boards.xml");
$products[0] = $xml->xpath("/sioctBoardPost/sioccontent")[0];
$products[1] = $xml->xpath("/sioctBoardPost/dctermscreated")[0];
$products[2] = $xml->xpath("/sioctBoardPost/@rdfabout")[0];
print_r($products);
```

Comment: But I have 5.3.5 and above code give following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\wamp\www\temptry.php on line 10

Comment: Could you provide your XML above in your question?

Comment: <sioctBoardPost rdfabout="http//boards.ie/vbulletin/showpost.php?p=67075"> <rdftype rdfresource="http//rdfs.org/sioc/ns#Post" /> <dctitle>hib team</dctitle> <siochas_creator> <siocUser rdfabout="http//boards.ie/vbulletin/member.php?u=497#user"> <rdfsseeAlso rdfresource="http//boards.ie/vbulletin/sioc.php?sioc_type=user&amp;sioc_id=497"/‌​> </siocUser> </siochas_creator> <dctermscreated>1998-04-25T213200Z</dctermscreated> <sioccontent>zero, those players that are trialing 300 -400 pingers? umm..mager lagg and even worse/</sioccontent> </sioctBoardPost>

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you need...

```
foreach ($products as $product) { // iterate through the $products array
    print $product[0]->nodeValue  // output the node value of the SimpleXMLElement Object
}
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but it does not show any thing as output, a blank screen appears